# Hightchart map pie : clic and hide specific pie

Tags: javascript, highcharts

how can I hide a specific pie from a states when I'm clicking on this states ?
For example on this map :

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-pies/

```
    series: [{
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
        data: data,
        name: 'States',
        ....
        events: {
           click: function (e) {
           e.point.zoomTo();
           chart.update({
              -- hide the state's pie
              -- display data from serie on this specific state
             })
           }
        }
```

I would like to hide California's Pie and zoom on this states to display an other serie of data instead (point for example)...

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the right series and use `setVisible` metohd:

```
    events: {
        click: function(e) {
            e.point.zoomTo();

            Highcharts.find(chart.series, function(item) {
                return item.name === e.point.id;
            }).setVisible(false, false);
        }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/czav0kL3/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible

Comment: Perfect ! better than my own solution ! Thanks a lot